# Is Devika river mentioned in any Hindu scripture?

Tags: scripture, ganga

Devika river located in Udhumpur (J&K). There are many folk stories about it being Ganga's bigger sister and about getting a curse and boon.

In the burial place of Devak river, even bones of dead can't survive the fire, only ashes remains. And its said that the burial place of Devika river never remain empty and at-least one person's always comes everyday for burial and its part of that boon or curse. Even it is said to be cursed for being non popular. But I can't find any Purana/Veda or any scripture on this holy river.

Is there any scripture mentioning this holy river and about her curse and boon? And her relationship to Ganga?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Vedas mention the sanctity of Devika and consider it as a powerful source to attain divinity. The river Devika is called the elder sister of the holy river Ganga. In Padma Purana, Lord Krishna once said to Yudhishtra, **‘Even river Ganga, when becomes overburdened by the sins of the evil-doers bathing for purification,** herself comes to bathe in the Devika to get rid of that weight.’*

**As you asked that is there any mention of Devika River in Purana I am adding it to show that there are many mentioned of Devika In Many Scriptures but nowhere it's been told that she got boon or curse.It will be helpful if someone finds the story of her boon and curse.**

*As mentioned in various scriptures that Parvati and Ganga Both are Sister and daughter of King Himavat and
queen Menavati and according to Nilmat Purana Parvati is famous on the earth as Devika River so it is proved that Ganga and Devika Both are sisters.
[Here](http://ikashmir.net/nilmatapurana/verses101-200.html) is the Source that Parvati  is Famous as Devika on earth.*

> Brought downby your honour for doing favour to the Madras, it is the goddess Uma who is famous on the earth as Devika and by seeing whom a man certainly becomes purified in this world.

[Here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/vamanapurana-12.htm) is The sacred River Devika as mentioned in Vamana Purana

> Shukracharya started making preparations for Ashwamedha Yagya at the bank of **River Devika** He appointed his disciples and some other sages belonging to Bhargava’s clan to supervise the Yagya ceremony. The Ashwamedha Yagya commenced and a horse was let loose according to the tradition.
> When the deities came to know about this Ashwamedha Yagya being performed by Dhundhu, they were scared and requested Lord Vishnu to disrupt the Yagya so that Dhundhu could not reach Brahma loka. Lord Vishnu assured the deities and went to the site where Dhundhu was performing Ashwamedha Yagya in a dwarf appearance. He entered into the **Devika River** and started drowning according to his plan.

[Here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/nilamatapurana.htm) is another mention of Devika river in Nilamatapurana

> 112-13. (There are) Kumbhavasunda possessed of holy water, the river Devika possessed of holy water, the great river Visvamitra which is sacred always, (the river) called Udda which is highly sacred and the various confluences (of the rivers). The religious merit (lies) in the Iravati and also in the Devika.

The Sacred river devika as mentioned in [Vishnupurana](http://www.astrojyoti.com/vishnupurana-5.htm)

> The teacher and the pupil used to live in the banks of the river Devika, near a city known as Viranagara, but Ribhu realized that Nidagha was still not ready for the supreme knowledge.

As Discussed in Mahabharata [Vana Parva : Tirth Yatra Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03082.htm)

> Having bathed in Devika and worshipped Maheswara by offering him, to the best of one's might, rice boiled in milk and butter, a man obtaineth, O bull of the Bharata race, the merit of a sacrifice that is capable of filling every desire. There also is another tirtha of Rudra called Kamakhya, which is much resorted to by the gods. Bathing there, a man speedily obtaineth success. By touching also the water of Yajana. Brahmavaluka, and Pushpamva, one becometh free from sorrow in after life. The learned have said that the sacred tirtha of Devika, the resort of the gods and the Rishis, is five Yojanas in length and half a Yojana in breadth.

## EDIT:

**Reasons for No**:
It is quite difficult to find a clear reference in any scripture which says that Devika and Ganga are sisters.

**Reasons for Yes**
As i referenced above that it was Parvati who is famous on earth as Devika river and Parvati was Sister of Ganga so Logically it's clear that Devika too is sister of Ganga.

Comment: could you please tell me on what page devika river has been referred in Padma Puran ? i am trying to find the reference you have posted above